# Regular Expression for a string that should contain only one asterisk (*)

Tags: javascript, regex

String can contain anything, but must have one asterisk (`*`) throughout the string and that asterisk can be anywhere in the string.

Also string should not contain any blank spaces.

Following are valid strings:

```
test*
*_test
test*something
```

Following are invalid strings:

```
test_**
**_test
test*something*
test *something
test *
testsomething
*
```

Someone please help me writing a regex for the above scenario.

Comment: Is a one-character string that is just an asterisk valid?

Comment: So it's a string that starts with zero or more non-asterisk characters, followed by a single asterisk, followed by zero or more non-asterisk characters?

Comment: Asterisk can be anywhere in the string.But, should have only one asterisk.If there is no asterisk in the string then it's invalid.Also, If there are more than one asterisk in the string then it's invalid.If there is one asterisk then it's a valid string it must return 'true'

Comment: @nnnnnn no,it's not a valid string

Comment: `^[^*\s]*\*[^*\s]*$`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Your regex will allow whitespace. The regex mentioned before by me is correct.

Comment: @Boratzan ya, failed to see the question's second part.

Comment: Another one `^(?:(?!\*)\S)*\*(?:(?!\*)\S)*$`

Comment: Guys, it should not allow asterisk alone.That means string must contain some characters. It can either before or after the asterisk.

Answer (score 4):

Use this RegEx:

```
^(?!(.*?\*){2,}|.*? |\*$).*?\*.*$
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/aI1tI9/1)</kbd>

If you want it to allow tabs (all other whitespace), use `\s` instead of a literal <kbd>Space</kbd> ():

```
^(?!(.*?\*){2,}|.*?\s|\*$).*?\*.*$
```

How it works:

```
^          # String starts with ...
(?!        # DO NOT match if ...
  (.*?\*)    # Optional Data followed by a *
  {2,}       # Multiple times (multiple *s)
  |          # OR
  .*?\s      # Optional Data followed by whitespace
  |          # OR
  \*$        # * then the end of the string (i.e. whole string is just a *)
)
.*?        # Optional Data before *
\*         # *
.*         # Optional Data after *
$          # ... String ends with
```

---

Demo:

```js
strings = [
  'test*',
  '*_test',
  'test*something',
  'test',
  '*',
  'test_**',
  '**_test',
  'test*something*',
  'test *something',
  'test *'
]

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  if (strings[i].match(/^(?!(.*?\*){2,}|.*?\s|\*$).*?\*.*$/)) {
    document.write(strings[i] + '<br>')
  }
}
```

Comment: You are currently incorrectly matching a string without asterisk, that should not be valid.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot believe I made much a silly mistake! Updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/^[^*\s]*\*[^*\s]*$/` to check for a string, that contains exactly one asterisk and no spaces. If only a single asterisk is invalid, you should add a lookahead to check for the presence of at leats two characters like `/^(?=.{2})[^*\s]*\*[^*\s]*$/`

See https://regex101.com/r/yE5zV2/1 for some samples (go to unit tests)

Comment: `If only a single asterisk is invalid` ?? ur 1st regex is enough.

Comment: @AvinashRaj according to comments a string cotaining only a single asterisk should not match, so I included that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
var regex = /^([^ \*]|\s)*\*{1}([^ \*]|\s)*$/

var str1 = '*abcfkdsjfksdjf';
var str2 = 'abcfkds*jfksdjf';
var str3 = 'abcfkdsjfksdjf*';
var str4 = 'abcfkdsjfksdjf';
var str5 = 'abcf*kdsjfk*sdjf';



console.log(regex.test(str1)); // returns true;
console.log(regex.test(str2)); // returns true;
console.log(regex.test(str3)); // returns true;
console.log(regex.test(str4)); // returns false;
console.log(regex.test(str5)); // returns false;
```

Comment: Maybe throw in some tests for multiple asterix or spaces?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser check my updated answer, and thanks for your feedback by the way

Comment: it should allow tabs..

Comment: @AvinashRaj, thx for your feedback, now all the  white space characters(\s) are matched except the space character.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions hardly require any regex (good to use when checking for whitespace though).

```js
// This is the checking function
function checkStr(x) {
  return (x.indexOf("*", x.indexOf("*")+1) === -1 && x.indexOf("*") > -1 && !/\s/.test(x));
}
// And this is the demo code
var valid = ["123*567", "*hereandthere", "noidea*"];
var invalid = ["123*567*", "*here and there", "noidea**", "kkkk"];
valid.map(x => document.body.innerHTML += "<b>" + x + "</b>: " + checkStr(x) + "<br/><b>");
invalid.map(x => document.body.innerHTML += "<b>" + x + "</b>: " + checkStr(x) + "<br/><b>");
```

The POI is `return (x.indexOf("*", x.indexOf("*")+1) === -1 && x.indexOf("*") > -1 && !/\s/.test(x));`:

- `x.indexOf("*", x.indexOf("*")+1) === -1` - makes sure there are no 2 asterisks
- `x.indexOf("*") > -1` - makes sure there is at least one `*`
- `!/\s/.test(x)` -  makes sure there is no whitespace in the string.